# Partition an array in order

Tags: algorithm

This is an interview question that a friend of mine got and I'm unable to come up with how to solve it.

**Question:**

You are given a array of n buttons that are either red or blue. There are k containers present. The value of a container is given by the product of red buttons and blue buttons present in it. The problem is to put the buttons into the containers such that the sum of all values of the containers is minimal. Additionally, all containers must contain the buttons and they must be put in order they are given.
For example, the very first button can only go to the first container, the second one can go to either the first or the second but not the third (otherwise the second container won't have any buttons).
k will be less than or equal to n.

I think there must be a dynamic programming solution for this.

How do you solve this ?
So far, I've only got the trivial cases where

- if (n==k), the answer would be zero because you could just put one in each container making the value of each container zero, therefore the sum would be zero.
- if (k==1), you just dump all of them and calculate the product.
- if only one color is present, the answer would be zero.

**Edit**:

I'll give an example.

n = 4 and k = 2

Input: R B R R

The first container gets the first two (R and B) making its value 1 (1R X 1B)
The second container gets the remaining (R and R) making its value 0 (2R x 0B)
The answer is 1 + 0 = 1

if k=3, 
the first container would have only the first button (R)
the second container would have only the second one (B)
the third one would have the last two buttons (R and R)
Each of the containers would have value 0 and hence sum and answer would be 0.

Hope this clears up the doubts.

Comment: If `n >> k`, and we are at step `k + 1`, and all containers contain exactly one button so far, can the `k + 1`th button go into any container? I don't understand why you can't put the second button into the third container. If you have enough buttons you can still fill the second container later.

Comment: I'm sorry, but your example only makes me more confused. Why don't you first put the first `r` into the first container, the second `b` into the second container, and the next two `r` into the first container, getting the sum of `0`?

Comment: @IVlad: The buttons have to be put in the order they are given. Meaning the first i buttons go into the first container, the next j buttons into the second one, the next k ones into the third and so forth.

Comment: If I understand correctly, for even k it is always possible to make sum 0. Put buttons of same color in first container, when color change move to next container. For odd k greedy algorithm is to choose between last and first container to mix colors, other containers contain one color.

Comment: I think I finally understood `Coder25` problem. The main constraint is that you must fill the containers in order: that is, you have the input stream `R B R R` and the only action you can do is "move to next container" (and there is no backward move). Another definition would be that given a sequence of length `N` elements from `{R, B}` and `K` containers, you need to provide `K-1` indices such that the `i`th container will contain the elements between indices `i` and `i+1`.

Comment: @Matthieu: I also understood that way.

Answer (score 4):

Possible DP solution:

Let `dp[i, j] = minimum number possible if we put the first i numbers into j containers`.

`dp[i, j] = min{dp[p, j - 1] + numRed[p+1, i]*numBlues[p+1, i]}, p = 1 to i - 1`

Answer will be in `dp[n, k]`.

```
int blue = 0, red = 0;
for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i)
{
    if (buttons[i] == 1)
        ++red;
    else
        ++blue;

    dp[i][1] = red * blue;
}

for (int i = 2; i <= n; ++i)
    for (int j = 2; j <= k; ++j)
    {
        dp[i][j] = inf;

        for (int p = 1; p <= i; ++p)
            dp[i][j] = min(dp[p][j - 1] + getProd(p + 1, i), dp[i][j]);
    }

return dp[n][k];
```

Complexity will be `O(n^3*k)`, but it's possible to reduce to `O(n^2*k)` by making `getProd` run in `O(1)` with the help of certain precomputations (**hint**: use `dp[i][1]`). I'll post it tomorrow if no one figures out this is actually wrong until then.

It might also be possible to reduce to `O(n*k)`, but that will probably require a different approach...

Comment: Can you please explain this solution ?

Comment: @Coder25 - if we know the answer for `1, 2, 3, ... i` numbers into `1, 2, 3, ..., j` containers then we have to think of a way of using this information to find the answer for `i` numbers into `j + 1` containers. We need to find a split point `p` somewhere between `1` and `i - 1` where numbers `1 -> p` and `p + 1 -> i` will go into two different containers. Choose the split point that generates the minimum sum.

Comment: @lVlad: minor nitpick -- I am dubious of the `p = 1 to i-1`, while it might not affect the correctness of the algorithm and could prove an optimization, since containers may be empty, I'd say let `p` float until `i` included. Otherwise the algorithms seems right, though the complexity is scary... in a real implementation I'd probably add a check to stop the inner loop if `dp[i][j]` get to 0 (since it cannot get lower than that), but it doesn't change the worse case.

Comment: @Matthieu M. - sounds right, I edited it to go until `i` included.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand the question correctly, as long as every container has at least one button in it, you can choose any container to put the remaining buttons in.  Given that, put one button in every container, making sure that there is at least one container with a red button and at least one with a blue button. Then with the remaining buttons, put all the red buttons in a container with a red button and put all the blue buttons in a container with blue buttons in it.  This will make it so every container has at least one button and every container has only one color of buttons.  Then every container's score is 0.  Thus the sum is 0 and you have minimized the combined score.

Comment: What if your first `k` buttons are all red and the `k + 1`-th is blue and you only have `k + 1` buttons? You need to use all the containers according to the OP, so how will you know to put the `k`th button into the first container and use the `k`th container for the blue button? Can you run your algorithm on this example?

Comment: The question is a bit confusing, but I think that "all containers must contain the buttons and they must be put in order they are given" implies that even if every container has a button the order still matters.  So `n[i+1]` cannot be in an earlier container than `n[i]`.  OP correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Andrew The question states that the second button can go into either the first or the second container, but not the third. This means that the `ith` button can go into any of the `i-1` containers, but not the ones after `i-1`, assuming 0 based indexing.

Comment: @efficiencyIsBliss What you say is true, so is what I said, they do not contradict each other.  My comment states that if button 2 is placed in container 2 then button 3 cannot be placed in container 1.

Answer (score 3):

**Warning: Proven to be non-optimal**

How about a greedy algorithm to get people talking?  I'm not going to try to prove it's optimal at this point, but it's a way of approaching the problem.

In this solution, we use the G to denote the number of contiguous regions of one colour in the sequence of buttons.  Say we had (I'm using x for red and o for blue since R and B look too similar):

```
x x x o x o o o x x o
```

This would give G = 6.  Let's split this into groups (red/blue) where, to start with, each group gets an entire region of a consistent colour:

```
3/0  0/1  1/0  0/3  2/0  0/1  //total value: 0
```

When G <= k, you have a minimum of zero since each grouping can go into its own container.  Now assume G > k.  Our greedy algorithm will be, while there are more groups than containers, collapse two **adjacent** groups into one that result in the least container value *delta* (`valueOf(merged(a, b)) - valueOf(a) - valueOf(b)`).  Say k = 5 with our example above.  Our choices are:

```
Collapse 1,2: delta = (3 - 0 - 0) = 3
         2,3: delta = 1
         3,4: delta = 3
         4,5: delta = 6
         5,6: delta = 2
```

So we collapse 2 and 3:

```
3/0  1/1  0/3  2/0  0/1  //total value: 1
```

And k = 4:

```
Collapse 1,2: delta = (4 - 0 - 1) = 3
         2,3: delta = (4 - 1 - 0) = 3
         3,4: delta = (6 - 0 - 0) = 6
         4,5: delta = 2

3/0  1/1  0/3  2/1   //total value: 3
```

k = 3

```
4/1  0/3  2/1  //total value: 6
```

k = 2

```
4/1  2/4  //total value: 12
```

k = 1

```
6/5  //total value: 30
```

It seems optimal *for this case*, but I was just intending to get people talking about a solution.  Note that the starting assignments of buttons to containers was a shortcut: you could instead start with each button in the sequence in its own bucket and then reduce, but you would always arrive to the point where each container has the maximum number of buttons of one colour.

**Counterexample:** Thanks to **Jules Olléon** for providing a counter-example that I was too lazy to think of:

```
o o o x x o x o o x x x
```

If k = 2, the optimal mapping is

```
2/4  4/2  //total value: 16
```

Let's see how the greedy algorithm approaches it:

```
0/3  2/0  0/1  1/0  0/2  3/0  //total value: 0

0/3  2/0  1/1  0/2  3/0  //total value: 1

0/3  3/1  0/2  3/0  //total value: 3

0/3  3/1  3/2  //total value: 9

3/4  3/2  //total value: 18
```

I'll leave this answer up since it's accomplished its only purpose of getting people talking about a solution.  I wonder if the greedy heuristic could be used in an informed search algorithm such as A* to improve the runtime of an exhaustive search, but that would not achieve polynomial runtime.

Comment: I think the idea is good, but you slipped up on the details:  for k==4, shouldn't you colapse 4&5 for a total value of 3?

Comment: @AShelly: whoops, thanks, can't even follow my own algorithm!  Don't think it affects the later ones since you just collapse 1/2 for k = 3 instead; they switch.

Comment: Just a warning:  my gut feeling is that this won't be optimal.  I can't spend too much time thinking about a proof sketch right now.  Instead I might try it with tons of test data later to see if it works in practice.

Comment: My gut feeling is, this might be optiomal. I tried to start a proof in a separate answer.

Comment: It seems to me that this would yield an O(N(N-K)) complexity if it is correct (which is better than the DP solution presented by lVlad), could anyone confirm this ?

Comment: Mark, your gut feeling is right, this is not optimal: consider oooxxoxooxxx for k=2. The optimal split is in the middle and has a total value of 16. Your algorithm's first step would be to group the 2 middle buttons, which is wrong (total value would be 18).

Answer (score 1):

I always ask for clarifications of the problem statement in an interview. Imagine that you never put blue an red buttons together. Then the sum is 0, just like n==k. So, for all cases where k > 1, then the minimum is 0.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I understand so far: The algorithm is to process a sequence of values {R,B}. 
It may choose to put the value in the current container or the next, if there is a next.

I first would ask a couple of questions to clarify the things I don't know yet:

- Is k and n known to the algorithm in advance? I assume so.
- Do we know the full sequence of buttons in advance?
- If we don't know the sequence in advance, should the average value minimized? Or the maximum (the worst case)?

Idea for a proof for the algortihm by Mark Peters

Edit: Idea for a proof (sorry, couldn't fit it in a comment)

Let L(i) be the length of the ith group. Let d(i) be the diff you get by collapsing container i and i+1 => d(i) = L(i)*L(i+1).

We can define a distribution by the sequence of containers collapsed. As index we use the maximum index of the original containers contained in the collapsed container containing the containers with the smaller indexes.

A given sequence of collapses I = [i(1), .. i(m)] results in a value which has a lower bound equal to the sum of d(i(m)) for all m from 1 to n-k.

We need to proof that there can't be a sequence other then the one created by the algorithm with a smaller diff. So let the sequence above be the one resulting from the algorithm. Let J = [j(1), .. j(m)].

Here it gets skimpy: 
I think it should be possible to proof that the lower limit of J is larger then the actual value of I because in each step we choose by construction the collapse operation from I so it must be smaller then the matching collapse from the alternate sequence

I think we might assume that the sequences are disjunct, but I'm not completely sure about it.

Comment: n, k and the sequence of buttons are given in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a brute force algorithm written in Python which seems to work.

```
from itertools import combinations
def get_best_order(n, k):
    slices = combinations(range(1, len(n)), k-1)
    container_slices = ([0] + list(s) + [len(n)] for s in slices)
    min_value = -1
    best = None
    def get_value(slices, n):
        value = 0
        for i in range(1, len(slices)):
            start, end = slices[i-1], slices[i]
            num_red = len([b for b in n[start:end] if b == 'r'])
            value += num_red * (end - start - num_red)
        return value
    for slices in container_slices:
        value = get_value(slices, n)
        if value < min_value or min_value == -1:
            min_value = value
            best = slices
    return [n[best[i-1]:best[i]] for i in range(1, len(best))]
n = ['b', 'r', 'b', 'r', 'r', 'r', 'b', 'b', 'r']
k = 4
print(get_best_order(n, k))
# [['b', 'r', 'b'], ['r', 'r', 'r'], ['b', 'b'], ['r']]
```

Basically the algorithm works like this:

- Generate a list of every possible arrangement (items stay in order, so this is just a number of items per container)
- Calculate the value for that arrangement as described by the OP
- If that value is less than the current best value, save it
- Return the arrangement that has the lowest value